# Azure https redirection not working for application rest service httpStatus:301

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For my Web Java application, Which is deployed on Azure VM I have done the http to https redirection on azure waf listener. which looks working fine on web but not for rest webservices. 
For example: When I access the http url like http: //www.abc.com it will automatically redirect to https: //www.abc.com.

But when I am trying to access the rest post webservice with http for example: http: //www.abc.com/rs/savedata it gives error with status code -301 and status message "Moved Permanently".

However when we access rest post api with https it works fine.

I am not sure what configuration is required on Azure, so that it can automatically redirect to https for http rest request.

Comment: A 301 is a redirect isn't it? It's the client's responsibility to follow it.

Comment: yes @juunas but we need to give support to our earlier releases of applications which are using rest api with http.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308908/gauravratnawat  I think you need to check the reverse proxy as a solution below

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior that is described in here: you will have to manage it from the client to call the new redirect to URL as described in here:
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-redirect-overview

if you want transparent redirect you will need to look at putting in place a Reverse Proxy Like Nginx which will handle the redirect and make a pass through.

Comment: i tried to do this on VM via apache httpd but have not succeed.  i think we have to take the first solution : will have to manage it from the client to call the new redirect to URL . Right? or do we have any other solution

Comment: I don't suggest apache but Nginx reverse proxy , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching. Otherwise you have to manage this from the client. So it will replace application gateway.